# Where will be nohup file created/stored

Tags: linux, shell

On executing below given command within a script file:

Command :

```
nohup /usr/hp/ism/jboss-3.2.8.SP1/bin/run.sh &
```

Where will the nohup.out file be created, assuming that script is running in root directory ?

Comment: nohup.out will be generated in whatever directory you executed the command from.

Comment: mysqladmin -u root -p -i 1 processlist

Comment: https://zeldor.biz/2010/11/mysql-show-processlist-every-second/

Comment: @shaahiin comment i wrong. if permissions are insufficient `nohup` will write in the home directory of the user running the `nohup` command.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Could you check home directory.

also you can redirect as below;

```
nohup /usr/hp/ism/jboss-3.2.8.SP1/bin/run.sh &> /tmp/nohup.out
```

> man nohup ;
>
> If standard input is a terminal, redirect it from /dev/null.  If
>   standard output is a terminal, append output to 'nohup.out' if
>   possible, '$HOME/nohup.out' otherwise.  If standard error is a
>   terminal, redirect it to standard
>          output.  To save output to FILE, use 'nohup COMMAND > FILE'.

Comment: No, basically its a script to start a service, and the details of starting that service will be logged in nohup file, so where that nohup file will be created?

Answer (score 1):

Running a python code using nohup and & the nohub.out was in the same directory as the command was run from

pwd output:

```
/home/dv/project7
```

command run:

```
nohup python3 /home/dv/project7/test_code_v3.1.py &
```

ls -l output:

```
test_code_v3.1.py
nohup.out
```

I think a better way is so that your program outputs to your own error log file vs. stdout thgerefore to nohub.out